# My Canon LBP6020B printer doesn't forward anything from the printer queue

Tags: 14.04, printing, canon, 14.10

I can't use my Canon LBP6020B printer on my Ubuntu 14.10 installation. I couldn't use it with 14.04 either.

I have installed Canon drivers with a help of GDebi: `cndrvcups-capt_2.60-1_amd64.deb`. ([Official Canon LBP6020 printer driver download](http://support-sg.canon-asia.com/contents/SG/EN/0100459601.html).)

My printout appears in the print queue but nothing happens: it just says "processing" forever.

I am an Ubuntu user with a very little knowledge of Linux (switched from Windows 7 a month ago). I spent days to solve the problem, and even installed VirtualBox with Windows 7 and the from there I can print. The problem with VirtualBox is that it always comes up with a different issue (mouse do not leave the VirtualBox window, etc.) so it's not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the Readme for the CAPT v2.60 driver, since you have 64 bit you will need to install 32bit versions of some files. Here is the excerpt from the Readme.

- About printing from 64-bit version Ubuntu
  Because a common module is installed with 64-bit Ubuntu, a 64-bit version
  libglade2 library is required.
  You can install the libglade2 library by executing the following command.

  ```
  # apt-get install libglade2
  ```
- In a 64-bit Ubuntu environment, all the 32-bit libraries required for
  printing are not installed. As a result, printing will fail if 32-bit
  libraries are not installed.
  Before printing, it is required that you execute the following commands to
  install a 32-bit library package.

  ```
  # apt-get install ia32-libs
  # apt-get install libpopt0:i386
  ```